# How to I make a domain resolve to different IP's when resolved from internal network and external network?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, nameserver, dnsmasq, digital-ocean

So I looked through BIND and Dnsmasq and unable to figure this out.

I have a few of servers on DigitalOcean, and they are on the same datacenter. I want to be able to use internal IPs to get better intra network pings and (obviously, free private network traffic). 
Given the following two servers:

```
Name   Public IP          Private IP
srv1   192.0.2.1          10.10.10.1
srv2   198.51.100.2       10.10.10.2
```

When digging from external network (say my laptop), I want something like this

```
account.codingblocks.com. 79    IN  CNAME   srv2.cb.lk.
srv2.cb.lk.               85844 IN  A       198.51.100.2
```

When digging from inside srv1, I want this instead

```
account.codingblocks.com. 79    IN  CNAME   srv2.cb.lk.
srv2.cb.lk.               85844 IN  A       10.10.10.2
```

Is this possible ? If yes, how.

Comment: Please use IP reserved for examples and not some made up, see RFC5737

Comment: The feature you're looking for is called *split-horizon DNS*.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In BIND 9, you can define multiple "views": in effect, BIND shows one version of a DNS zone to specified clients and another version to others. This seems to be exactly what you'll need.

Here is a nice introduction to using views in BIND 9:
https://kb.isc.org/article/AA-00851/0/Understanding-views-in-BIND-9-by-example.html

In your case, though, the external view would say:

```
match-clients { any; };
```

rather than specifying any network segments.

Answer (score 2):

There are at least 3 solutions :

- you can use /etc/hosts to override DNS answers
- you can use a second tld eg account.codingblocks.com would give 222.222.222.222 and account.example.mytld would give 10.10.10.2
- you can have 2 different DNS servers (one private and internal and the other public) that would give different results.

Comment: If I add `10.10.10.2 srv2.cb.lk` to my /etc/hosts will the recursive lookup for `account.codingblocks.com` also work ?

Comment: I don't remember (I think the answer is no), but you can try on your laptop.

Comment: It's terrible advice, imho. With bind you should use - views

Comment: as @ALex_hha already stated, this is wrong. Look at the other answer

Comment: imho using private DNS servers for private IP increases security... and bind is not the only dns server

Comment: I know that bind is not the only dns server, but OP asked about it. Also split horizon supports a lot of other dns servers - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_DNS_server_software#Feature_matrix